# When there is need to do serialization of datatype and how to serialize data type

Tags: autosar

I Found that in some arxml file DataType used in interfaces are just a array type data.Which looks like they are serialized for data mapping purpose.

My question is when there is need to serialize datatype while referring in interfaces.And how to serialize datatype.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialization of composite data types is applicable when using the SOME/IP transport layer on Ethernet physical channels. The details of how data types are serialized are explained in the AUTOSAR specification (SWS) of the SOME/IP transformer.

Comment: Not only on Ethernet. Also CAN/CAN-FD needs (de-)serialization for big data. Especially in the ADAS world, with sensor data fusion of camera, radar and other is necessary. Ethernet is just too expensive to put it on every sensor.